# Minify_YUICompressor::minifyCss too long load time in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, minify, profiler

I'm debuggin my magento store to find some bottlenecks. I've very high waiting time in firebug loading my ecommerce. I found that voice Minify_YUICompressor::minifyCss that take about 3,4250 and I don't understand what is it... I've activate the minify css but I don't think it must be executed each time I load the page right?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that was the optimization website tool on siteground hosting that was causing that. I've disabled it